# Zabbix server and agent 6.0 on kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm migrating Zabbix 5.0.4 from VM to Kubernetes to version 6.0.0. The MySQL migration is going fine backup and restore works. With what I have a problem is connection between agent and server.

For agent I'm using official Zabbix [helm chart](https://git.zabbix.com/projects/ZT/repos/kubernetes-helm/browse?at=refs%2Fheads%2Frelease%2F6.0), and for server the [cetic](https://github.com/cetic/helm-zabbix) one.

You can add them like this

```sh
helm repo add cetic https://cetic.github.io/helm-charts
helm repo add zabbix-chart-6.0 https://cdn.zabbix.com/zabbix/integrations/kubernetes-helm/6.0
helm repo update
```

Config for agent looks like this

```sh
zabbixProxy:
  enabled: false

zabbixAgent:
  ## If true, agent pods mounts host / at /host/root
  hostRootFsMount: false

  image:
    repository: zabbix/zabbix-agent
    tag: alpine-6.0.3
  env:
    - name: ZBX_SERVER_HOST
      value: "internal-company.domain"
    - name: ZBX_PASSIVESERVERS
      value: 0.0.0.0/0
    - name: ZBX_DEBUGLEVEL
      value: 5
      ## The variable is used to specify timeout for processing checks. By default, value is 4.
    - name: ZBX_TIMEOUT
      value: 10
```

and for server it looks like this

```sh
zabbixserver:
  image:
    #repository: zabbix/zabbix-server-pgsql
    repository: "zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql" #https://hub.docker.com/r/zabbix/zabbix-server-pgsql
    tag: "ubuntu-6.0.3"

  # -- Address of database host
  DB_SERVER_HOST: "zabbix-mysql"
  # -- Port of database host
  DB_SERVER_PORT: "3306"

  # -- Extra environment variables. A list of additional environment variables. See example: https://github.com/cetic/helm-zabbix/blob/master/docs/example/kind/values.yaml
  #  taken from mysql config
  extraEnv:
    - name: "MYSQL_USER"
      value: "zabbixUser"
    - name: "MYSQL_PASSWORD"
      value: "zabbixPass"
    - name: "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
      value: "pass"
    - name: "MYSQL_DATABASE"
      value: "zabbix"

postgresql:
  enabled: false

zabbixproxy:
  enabled: false

zabbixagent:
  enabled: false

zabbixweb:
  image:
    repository: "zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-mysql" #https://hub.docker.com/r/zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-mysql
    #repository: zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-psql #https://hub.docker.com/r/zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-pgsql
    tag: "ubuntu-6.0.3"

  # -- Zabbix server host
  ZBX_SERVER_HOST: zabbix-server-zabbix-server
  # -- Address of database host
  DB_SERVER_HOST: zabbix-mysql
  # -- Port of database
  DB_SERVER_PORT: 3306

  extraEnv:
    - name: "MYSQL_USER"
      value: "zabbixUser"
    - name: "MYSQL_PASSWORD"
      value: "zabbixPass"
    - name: "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
      value: "pass"
    - name: "MYSQL_DATABASE"
      value: "zabbix"

ingress:
  enabled: true
  hosts:
    - host: internal-company.domain
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
  ingressClassName: nginx-internal
```

you can deploy it like this

```sh
# server
helm upgrade --install zabbix-server cetic/zabbix \
             --values server_values.yaml \
             --namespace monitoring \
             --version 1.1.1 \
             --debug

# agent
helm upgrade --install zabbix-agent zabbix-chart-6.0/zabbix-helm-chrt \
             --values temp_agent_values.yaml \
             --version 1.0.1 \
             --namespace monitoring \
             --debug
```

The error message I see when looking at `agent` logs is

```sh
736803:20220413:071814.827 In update_cpustats()
736803:20220413:071814.827 End of update_cpustats()
736803:20220413:071814.827 zbx_setproctitle() title:'collector [idle 1 sec]'
736807:20220413:071815.305 In send_buffer() host:'internal-company.domain' port:10051 entries:0/100
736807:20220413:071815.305 End of send_buffer():SUCCEED
736807:20220413:071815.305 zbx_setproctitle() title:'active checks #1 [getting list of active checks]'
736807:20220413:071815.305 In refresh_active_checks() host:'internal-company.domain' port:10051
736807:20220413:071815.305 In connect_to_server() [internal-company.domain]:10051 [timeout:10, connection timeout:10]
736807:20220413:071815.316 Unable to connect to [internal-company.domain]:10051 [cannot connect to [[internal-company.domain]:10051]: [111] Connection refused]
736807:20220413:071815.316 End of refresh_active_checks():FAIL
736807:20220413:071815.316 zbx_setproctitle() title:'active checks #1 [processing active checks]'
736807:20220413:071815.316 In process_active_checks() server:'internal-company.domain' port:10051
736807:20220413:071815.316 End of process_active_checks()
736807:20220413:071815.316 In get_min_nextcheck()
736807:20220413:071815.316 End of get_min_nextcheck():-1
736807:20220413:071815.316 zbx_setproctitle() title:'active checks #1 [idle 1 sec]'
736803:20220413:071815.827 zbx_setproctitle() title:'collector [processing data]'
736803:20220413:071815.827 In update_cpustats()
736803:20220413:071815.827 End of update_cpustats()
736803:20220413:071815.827 zbx_setproctitle() title:'collector [idle 1 sec]'
736807:20220413:071816.316 In send_buffer() host:'internal-company.domain' port:10051 entries:0/100
736807:20220413:071816.316 End of send_buffer():SUCCEED
736807:20220413:071816.316 zbx_setproctitle() title:'active checks #1 [idle 1 sec]'
736803:20220413:071816.827 zbx_setproctitle() title:'collector [processing data]'
736803:20220413:071816.827 In update_cpustats()
```

so

```sh
736807:20220413:071815.305 In connect_to_server() [internal-company.domain]:10051 [timeout:10, connection timeout:10]
```

the server logs say

```sh
   227:20220413:071305.527 [Z3005] query failed: [4031] The client was disconnected by the server because of inactivity. See wait_timeout and interactive_timeout for configuring this behavior. [select u.userid,u.roleid,u.username,r.type from sessions s,users u,role r where s.userid=u.userid and s.sessionid='5e2fbc17da7d33dc357302cb211a7c71' and s.status=0 and u.roleid=r.roleid]
```

and running the query on mysql shows this

```sh
mysql> select u.userid,u.roleid,u.username,r.type from sessions s,users u,role r where s.userid=u.userid and s.sessionid='5e2fbc17da7d33dc357302cb211a7c71' and s.status=0 and u.roleid=r.roleid;
+--------+--------+----------+------+
| userid | roleid | username | type |
+--------+--------+----------+------+
|      1 |      3 | Admin    |    3 |
+--------+--------+----------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

in addition to that, the zabbixUser is created

```sh
mysql> select user from mysql.user;
+------------------+
| user             |
+------------------+
| root             |
| zabbixUser       |
| mysql.infoschema |
| mysql.session    |
| mysql.sys        |
+------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any idea what is the problem and why my agent doesn't connect to server properly?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in

```sh
    - name: ZBX_SERVER_HOST
      value: "internal-company.domain"
```

When I set it to IP it started to work

Comment: actually it didn't solve the problem, I described it in more detail in this ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71894531/zabbix-6-0-agent-doesnt-collect-metrics-in-kubernetes-and-cant-talk-with-serve