# Zabbix 6.0 Agent doesn't collect metrics in Kubernetes and can't talk with server

Tags: kubernetes, zabbix

I've been setting up Zabbix Agent in kubernetes the past few days and I'm stuck on what I think is the most basic thing. I've created a brand new namespace, setup MySQL there and configured it, has the zabbixUser, pass and everything, I've setup Zabbix Server from [this](https://github.com/cetic/helm-zabbix) Helm Chart.

Here are the values files for it

```sh
zabbixserver:
  image:
    #repository: zabbix/zabbix-server-pgsql
    repository: "zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql" #https://hub.docker.com/r/zabbix/zabbix-server-pgsql
    tag: "ubuntu-6.0.3"

  DB_SERVER_HOST: "zabbix-mysql"
  DB_SERVER_PORT: "3306"

  # -- Extra environment variables. A list of additional environment variables. See example: https://github.com/cetic/helm-zabbix/blob/master/docs/example/kind/values.yaml
  #  taken from mysql config
  extraEnv:
    - name: "MYSQL_USER"
      value: "zabbixUser"
    - name: "MYSQL_PASSWORD"
      value: "zabbixPass"
    - name: "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
      value: "dyEMnUK69d"
    - name: "MYSQL_DATABASE"
      value: "zabbix"

postgresql:
  enabled: false

zabbixproxy:
  enabled: false
    #  # The variable is used to specify debug level, from 0 to 5
    #  ZBX_DEBUGLEVEL: 3
    #  ZBX_PROXYMODE: 1
    #  ZBX_SERVER_HOST: 10.190.8.122

# Installs zabbix agent next on the same pod as server
zabbixagent:
  enabled: true
  env:
    - name: ZBX_DEBUGLEVEL
      value: 4


zabbixweb:
  image:
    repository: "zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-mysql" #https://hub.docker.com/r/zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-mysql
    #repository: zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-psql #https://hub.docker.com/r/zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-pgsql
    tag: "ubuntu-6.0.3"

# kubectl get services
  ZBX_SERVER_HOST: zabbix-server-zabbix-server
  DB_SERVER_HOST: zabbix-mysql
  DB_SERVER_PORT: 3306

  extraEnv:
    - name: "MYSQL_USER"
      value: "zabbixUser"
    - name: "MYSQL_PASSWORD"
      value: "zabbixPass"
    - name: "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
      value: "dyEMnUK69d"
    - name: "MYSQL_DATABASE"
      value: "zabbix"

ingress:
  enabled: true
  hosts:
    - host: better-zabbix.genesis
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
  ingressClassName: nginx-internal
```

NOTE: It's hosted in my company's internal domain, and MySQL is also for testing purposes so no prod credentials.

I configured DNS as well so it all works as you can see.

[image]

Now I wanted to set up the Zabbix agent from [this](https://git.zabbix.com/projects/ZT/repos/kubernetes-helm/browse) official helm chart.

Here is also a useful [link](https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/kubernetes) showing ready templates to help get metrics from the GKE cluster - however, note that when you set up the Zabbix server from helm chart, he comes with them built-in. So I guess it's useful if you've got an older version and are on VM.

Here are my `values.yaml` for agent

```sh
zabbixAgent:
  image:
    repository: zabbix/zabbix-agent
    tag: alpine-6.0.3
  env:
    - name: ZBX_SERVER_HOST
      value: 10.190.40.58 # after zabbix server was created, this is the IP of his pod
      #value: 127.0.0.1
      #value: "better-zabbix.genesis"

zabbixProxy:
  enabled: false
rbac:
  create: false
serviceAccount:
  create: false
```

And now we get to the problem I have

```sh
Every 2.0s: kubectl get pods -o wide                                                                                                       colgate.local: Sat Apr 16 15:54:05 2022

NAME                                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP             NODE                                 NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
potato                                             1/1     Running   0          5h26m   10.190.4.102   gke-tools-single-nat-35d661ab-sf1c   <none>           <none>
zabbix-agent-7d4xv                                 1/1     Running   0          3h49m   10.222.0.59    gke-tools-single-nat-d4ec251a-hp7k   <none>           <none>
zabbix-agent-856lm                                 1/1     Running   0          3h46m   10.222.0.39    gke-tools-main-tools-bc42e123-6fpq   <none>           <none>
zabbix-agent-c5xtp                                 1/1     Running   0          3h47m   10.222.0.9     gke-tools-main-tools-bc42e123-ycgx   <none>           <none>
zabbix-agent-dn78k                                 1/1     Running   0          3h49m   10.222.0.98    gke-tools-single-nat-d4ec251a-i0a1   <none>           <none>
zabbix-agent-fbpzn                                 1/1     Running   0          3h49m   10.222.0.54    gke-tools-single-nat-d4ec251a-kxwn   <none>           <none>
zabbix-agent-gsvgt                                 1/1     Running   0          3h47m   10.222.0.51    gke-tools-main-tools-bc42e123-oc1i   <none>           <none>
zabbix-agent-h4bkn                                 1/1     Running   0          3h49m   10.222.0.50    gke-tools-single-nat-2dc0d382-1uv1   <none>           <none>
zabbix-agent-kube-state-metrics-5968c76968-6jb98   1/1     Running   0          3h59m   10.190.1.48    gke-tools-single-nat-d4ec251a-i0a1   <none>           <none>
zabbix-agent-pfs5s                                 1/1     Running   0          3h47m   10.222.0.55    gke-tools-single-nat-d4ec251a-4o43   <none>           <none>
zabbix-agent-plk7s                                 1/1     Running   0          3h46m   10.222.0.49    gke-tools-single-nat-35d661ab-xxsw   <none>           <none>
zabbix-agent-qm5c5                                 1/1     Running   0          3h48m   10.222.0.41    gke-tools-single-nat-35d661ab-m4ct   <none>           <none>
zabbix-agent-wk59p                                 1/1     Running   0          3h48m   10.222.0.5     gke-tools-single-nat-2dc0d382-zp2s   <none>           <none>
zabbix-agent-wl97k                                 1/1     Running   0          3h48m   10.222.0.88    gke-tools-main-tools-89255868-mxfl   <none>           <none>
zabbix-agent-z6vxh                                 1/1     Running   0          3h49m   10.222.0.46    gke-tools-single-nat-35d661ab-sf1c   <none>           <none>
zabbix-mysql-0                                     1/1     Running   0          3h59m   10.190.1.49    gke-tools-single-nat-d4ec251a-i0a1   <none>           <none>
zabbix-mysql-client                                1/1     Running   0          5h7m    10.190.0.215   gke-tools-single-nat-2dc0d382-zp2s   <none>           <none>
zabbix-server-zabbix-server-0                      2/2     Running   0          3h59m   10.190.2.99    gke-tools-single-nat-2dc0d382-1uv1   <none>           <none>
zabbix-server-zabbix-web-665c9b767-ssdt6           1/1     Running   0          3h59m   10.190.4.113   gke-tools-single-nat-35d661ab-sf1c   <none>           <none>
```

Logs from zabbix-agent pods are like this

```sh
3438519:20220416:135248.449 failed to accept an incoming connection: connection from "10.222.0.54" rejected, allowed hosts: "10.190.40.58"
```

So what does it mean? In zabbix-agent `values.yaml` I wrote that zabbix server host is

```sh
    - name: ZBX_SERVER_HOST
      value: 10.190.40.58
```

but the zabbix-agent says literally its own IP cannot be whitelisted? what does it all mean?

also, these are the logs from zabbix server

```sh
   208:20220416:135600.044 [ Kubernetes discovery ] ERROR: Incorrect JSON. Check debug log for more information.
   208:20220416:135600.045 [ Kubernetes discovery ] ERROR: Incorrect JSON. Check debug log for more information.
   226:20220416:135600.045 [ Kubernetes ] ERROR: Error: cannot get URL: Couldn't connect to server.
   208:20220416:135600.047 [ Kubernetes discovery ] ERROR: Incorrect JSON. Check debug log for more information.
   208:20220416:135600.048 [ Kubernetes discovery ] ERROR: Incorrect JSON. Check debug log for more information.
   226:20220416:135600.049 [ Kubernetes ] ERROR: Error: cannot get URL: Couldn't connect to server.
   208:20220416:135600.051 [ Kubernetes discovery ] ERROR: Incorrect JSON. Check debug log for more information.
   208:20220416:135600.052 [ Kubernetes discovery ] ERROR: Incorrect JSON. Check debug log for more information.
```

The autoregistration I have set up on zabbix-server works [image]

and we can see the hosts [image]

but the problem stays that agents can't get metrics/data from nodes [image]

I'll add that I configured the template with `token` [image]

As it was written in [this](https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/kubernetes) instructions in Zabbix Setup at the bottom of the page. Also, the one more unknown to me is the Zabbix configuration part from [here](https://git.zabbix.com/projects/ZBX/repos/zabbix/browse/templates/app/kubernetes_http/kubernetes_kubelet_http)  All these [image]
`{$KUBE.API.ENDPOINT.URL}` what should they point to ?

You guys would make my day by giving any hint as, why nodes are not seen, why agents apparently can't talk to the server, and whether should I change the `{$KUBE.API.ENDPOINT.URL}` or leave it as it was with default values.

Comment: I've also made another ticket few days ago in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71853660/zabbix-server-and-agent-6-0-on-kubernetes?rq=1

Comment: there is no `10.190.40.58` in `kubectl get pods` output. you did not whitelist the correct IP, so the agent is not accepting connections, so nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

`{$KUBE.API.ENDPOINT.URL}` this should point to `https://$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT`.

I get the values from a running pod. However, I did not try as a env value in Zabbix.